# Azure SQL Edge container on Raspberry Pi5 is not working

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, azure-sql-edge

I am trying to run Azure SQL Edge Docker container on my RPi5 running RaspbianOS Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64. BTW - On my RPi3B it was running fine.

I ran the command

```
sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 --name azuresqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

I created the container successfully, but I've got
`Stopped with exit code 1`

My log file:

```
Azure SQL Edge will run as non-root by default.
This container is running as user mssql.
To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2140520.
2024/01/30 10:17:53 [launchpadd] INFO: Extensibility Log Header: <timestamp> <process> <sandboxId> <sessionId> <message>
2024/01/30 10:17:53 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to load /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf ini file with error open /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf: no such file or directory
2024/01/30 10:17:53 [launchpadd] INFO: DataDirectories =  /bin:/etc:/lib:/lib32:/lib64:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/include:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:/usr/libexec/gcc:/usr/sbin:/usr/share:/var/lib:/opt/microsoft:/opt/mssql-extensibility:/opt/mssql/mlservices:/opt/mssql/lib/zulu-jre-11:/opt/mssql-tools
2024/01/30 10:17:53 Drop permitted effective capabilities.
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
*** the same around 500 times ***
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
Error in GnuTLS initialization: ASN1 parser: Element was not found.
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
<jemalloc>: Unsupported system page size
Out of memory allocating bitmask: Cannot allocate memory
```

I tried running docker command as Developer version and Premium version, but it gives the same problem.

Could it be that this container does not support ARM64?
[microsoft-azure-sql-edge](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge) Because I don't see it in the tags like before I ran it on RPi3B

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it was discontinued. Shame

> Azure SQL Edge based on ARM64 architecture is retired

[Link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/azure-sql-edge-update-september-2023/ba-p/3930827)